# Where is the "downloads" folder located

Tags: windows, powershell, filepath

I'm making a script in Powershell ISE and to prevent piracy a part of the script needs to locates the file name and if it exists on the computer the script won't work. This will work cause downloading a file twice will give it a little (1).

I've google all kind of questions but I just really want to figure out the file path to a file located in downloads.

Comment: Not that this has any bearing on the main thrust of your question, but what happens if the user has their web browser configured to prompt for a download location instead of auto-saving to `Downloads`? (I assume you're talking about browser downloads since I can't think of another application that downloads to that directory by default.) What if the user's browser doesn't resolve naming conflicts using that same `(#)` scheme? What if the user simply removes the anti-piracy code from your script? How does preventing multiple copies of the same file on the same computer prevent piracy, anyways?

Answer (score -13, accepted):

Ummm... C:/Users/*your name here*/Downloads

Put the name you registered your computer with as *your name here*

Comment: After Downloads put a slash then the file name and then the extension. Kind of like;

C:/Users/MrVillager10/Downloads/funnyimg.png

Comment: The downloads folder won't _always_ be in this location - they can be redirected via the registry: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`

Comment: @Jacob, if he had done that, why would he be asking this question?

Comment: They might not have done it personally, but the script might be deployed to an environment where the downloads folder is in a different location, in which case it will fail due to a false assumption. Although I think this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), because checking if a file exists by downloading something with the same name doesn't seem like a sound approach, especially as an anti-piracy method.

Comment: Unfortunately PowerShell's `[environment]::getfolderpath` is incomplete and appears to be limited to the old `CSIDL` special folders. PowerShell Core calls `SHGetKnownFolderPath` directly, so it should be able to support `FOLDERID_Downloads`. It just doesn't yet, which is weird since known folders were added way back in 2006 (Vista). Since they don't fully support it, we have to manually P/Invoke `SHGetKnownFolderPath` and define the required known-folder GUIDs.

Comment: @Jacob: Good point, but the registry method is deprecated on Windows 10 (the registry key has a string value named `!Do not use this registry key` with content `Use the SHGetFolderPath or SHGetKnownFolderPath function instead`).

Comment: @ErykSun: Good points, but you don't need to resort to P/Invoke, you can use the `Shell.Application` COM server from PowerShell.

Comment: @mklement0 yes, the problem with those registry keys is that they are only created when the shell folder is accessed, and whilst for downloads it shouldn't be a problem, it's definitely not a recommended approach. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031103-00/?p=41973

Comment: @MrVillager10: It's great that you want to contribute, but when valid criticisms are leveled against your answer and you don't address them, the answer deserves a down-vote.
Ideally, though, you'd _amend_ (or, if it isn't salvageable, _delete_) your answer - or, if you disagree with the criticisms - _seek a shared understanding_ through dialogue.
P.S.: Unless you specifically `@`-mention someone in comments on your own answer (you can only address 1person at a time), no one will be notified of your follow-up comments.

Comment: Seeing as how this ignores the intent of the question and answers it literally without presenting any code, I strongly suspect this answer treats it as a _user support_ question rather than a _programming_ question.  This is Stack Overflow, not Super User.  If the question were really about finding the literal, static, not-flexible-at-all path of a folder on one specific system (which maybe it is, since somehow this became the accepted answer), then the entire question is off-topic and should be closed as such.

Answer (score 49):

**tl;dr**

- The ***naive*<sup>[1]</sup> answer**, which *typically* but *not always* works:

```
"$HOME\Downloads"
```

- The ***robust answer***:

```
(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:Downloads').Self.Path
```

---

`"$HOME\Downloads"` assumes two things, which aren't *necessarily* true:

- That `$HOME`, which is equivalent to environment variable `USERPROFILE` (`$env:USERPROFILE`), is the root directory for the user's *documents* isn't always true, namely not with *roaming profiles* - only `"${env:HOMEDRIVE}${env:HOMEPATH}"` reliably reflects the documents folder.
- More importantly, the downloads folder may have been [*explicitly configured* to be in an *arbitrary location*](https://www.howtogeek.com/273618/how-do-you-change-windows-default-download-path/), unrelated to the documents location

**The only robust way to determine the downloads folder's location is to ask the *system* for it:**

PowerShell, as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.3, has no *PowerShell-native* way of asking the system for known folder locations.

- Adding such a feature has been [proposed on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6966), however.

While PowerShell has virtually unlimited access to the .NET framework and can therefore use the `System.Environment` type's [`.GetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath) method to ask for special known folders, the designated folder for downloads is - surprisingly - NOT among them.

**Only the WinAPI's [Known Folders API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/known-folders) allows retrieval of the designated downloads folders in a robust fashion**, without relying on fixed relationships with other known folders:

In PowerShell, you can access it via the `Shell.Application` COM server:

```bsh
(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:Downloads').Self.Path
```

For a list of all supported (`shell:`-prefixed) folder identifiers, see [this article](https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vista/shell/).

---

<sup>[1] By *naive* I mean: a solution that one is *understandably tempted* to use, but which doesn't work in *all* situations.</sup>

Comment: Regarding localization of known-folder directory names, since Vista (NT 6) the primary, default names are English. Localized installations of Windows in some cases use either junctions (like Unix bind mounts) or directory symbolic links (like Unix symlinks) to provide localized names at a low level in the file system, and at a high level the graphical shell shows localized names, but the preferred paths for applications and scripts to use are the common English names.

Comment: I upvoted even though I disagree on one point: I would call `"$HOME\Downloads"` the "quick-and-dirty" or "quick-and-not-necessarily-accurate" answer.  As for the "naive answer", I'd say that's something else entirely...

Comment: Thanks, @BACON, but I don't see a semantic difference between "quick-and-not-necessarily-accurate" and "which typically but not always works". Is it the word "naive" that you disagree with, and, if so, why? Please see the footnote I've added, which explains the intended semantics.

Comment: I, too, usually refer to a not-so-robust implementation to be the "naive approach."  My point was (in jest) that, all things considered, if there is a naive answer to this question, it's certainly not _this_ one.

Answer (score 1):

`$downloadsFolder = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders").PSObject.Properties["{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}"].Value`

Comment: This is not language-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

This should work os agnostic. On non Windows systems, there is no ComObject support.

```
$path =  Join-Path -Path "$([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath(40))" -ChildPath "Downloads"
```

Note that the folder "Downloads" is language dependent. .NET does not have a cross-platform call to detect this.